# Locate large files on Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, online-storage

I seem to have a storage issue on my Google Drive.

The storage used indicated on the home page, visible on the image below, is 5x larger than the storage used on my Home folder calculated with this application: http://gdrivefoldersize.appspot.com/.

[image]

I looked for large files through the 'quota' page, accessible with the 'i' button on the image.
Some were old files which I thought I deleted, and which I cannot locate on my drive (example on the left in the image below). Their location is not indicated, and there is even an 'add to my drive' option available. But they seem to take up space on my drive nevertheless.

[image]

My trash is empty.

How do I locate and clear these files from my drive?

Comment: 1) The files you deleted still might be in thr `Trash` - you can empty it. 2)  If you have backups (such as WhatsApp) - they're included in your total quota. 3) Is it possible (or make sense in your files) that the app calculate only the specific folder, or maybe also the first subdirs level - but not entirely recursive?

Comment: 1) My trash is empty.
2) I have no backups.
3) I don't think that the app calculates only the first subdirectory level. There are only a couple of files in this level, pretty much everything is stored in subdirectories.

Comment: I've found that it can take some time from the time you empty trash until the time the storage is recovered. Also, have you considered that maybe the _app_ is calculating it incorrectly?

Comment: I have emptied my trash weeks ago, so I don't think that it is a matter of time.
Yes the app might be calculating incorrectly. 
But I have no other way to calculate my whole storage space, other than the indication visible on the image that I posted in the question. And I don't trust this indication either, because Google Drive is showing me files which I deleted months ago in the quota page, and which I cannot locate in any of my folders. 
It is a plain mystery to me.

Comment: I have reopened this because you have added information that differentiates this question from the duplicate.